# What are the common words to describe the different parts of the sea?

Tags: word-usage, single-word-requests

OK, this is an attempt:

[image]

> I remained there, gazing at the sea. Its color was light green in
>   the part closest to the shore, turned slightly darker in the middle,
>   then abruptly changed to dark blue in deeper waters.

Are those words commonly used? Or is there a better and simpler terminology to describe them?

Comment: Do you want us to proofread your passage or are you looking for an informal or differently a technical taxonomy of a beach? Also Do you want the entire ocean system, or just what you can see in the picture? Please edit your question considerably to make more specific.

Comment: I think it's clear enough that he's looking for specific words for various parts of a beach.  Instead of "the part closest to shore" is there a word for which this is the definition?

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Yes, exactly.

Comment: In the macmillan dictionary there is a long list of words describing different [areas of water](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/Words-used-to-describe-areas-of-water).

Comment: I think that's useful, @Mari-LouA, but the question is asking about the terminology for the various depths of water in the inshore.  For which there doesn't seem to be anything more generic than "the shallows".

Comment: Agreed, that's why I only posted a comment. It's extra stuff for our friend to dip into.

Comment: There's also another rather thin band right at the shore where the water is cloudy from wave action.  If you're still looking for an answer you might check on sites devoted to diving and snorkeling.  Those people might have special terms for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be described as a gradual deepening of color from the ***water's edge*** to the dark, opaque ***depths*** at the distant horizon.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be only one common word for any part of the water next to the shore.  And that would be "shallows".  As in, "Its color was light green in the shallows..."

If there are any other words for the parts deeper than the shallows, and for the parts even deeper than that, I am unaware of them.

Edited to add:  That being said, there is a word for the part of the sea close to the shore, namely "inshore".  But it doesn't distinguish between the shallows and the deeper areas.  There are words for various parts that further out from inshore.  "Deeps" being one of them, but when we come to this we are not talking about the parts nearer the shore, which is the subject of your picture.

Answer (score 2):

The *offing* is the part of the sea visible from the shore (or, equivalently, from which you can see the land), but unless you use technical terms like *reef*, *bar* or *sandbank*, I do not think there are any more specific terms.

Comment: Nice!  Never heard that one before.  Just checked dictionary.com and now I know what is up with the usage "A wedding is in the offing."  Meaning, that I actually had heard it before, but wasn't aware of the full import of the word and its usage.

Comment: isn't the offing the navigable deep water between shore and horizon, specifically excluding inshore shallows?

Comment: @Spagirl: In my experience, "making an offing" is specifically reaching a point where you can see the shore: avoiding shallows is desirable but optional.