# Succinct description of where water meets land?

Tags: british-english, connotation, adjective-position

Assuming that "a water's edge" marginally connotes land, too: would it be correct English if "a water's edge" were joined by an adjective describing the nature of the land?

(examples: "a sandy water's edge"; "a muddy water's edge", etc.)

Comment: It sounds as though you mean that the water is muddy! I would recommend _shore, shoreline, beach, coast_ or similar, depending on context..

Comment: Yes, you can talk about a sandy water's edge and a sharp or rocky water's edge.  I'm not saying it's common but you can do that.

Comment: This may be of interest https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120041/what-are-the-common-words-to-describe-the-different-parts-of-the-sea

Answer (score 2):

You suggest a word that you could combine with descriptive adjectives; the most versatile is *shore*. An ocean, a river, and a (large) pond can all have a *shore*, and it can be sandy, muddy, rocky, etc.

Other notes, in addition to the words suggested by Kate:

- If the land meets the water with a steep drop-off, but less than a cliff (e.g. a meter), it's a *bank*. This can be occasionally used of oceans, but more often with rivers (*riverbank* is a valid compound).
- Your suggestion of "water's edge" is a common phrase, though more often used with "the" than "a," and less inclined to take adjectives.
- One note, since you tagged this "british-english": British usage in the past has often used *strand* for a sandy shore, where American and modern British usage would use "beach."

Comment: I'm not sure that many BrE speakers would immediately associate 'strand' with 'beach'. It is correct but perhaps a rather dated usage. Also unsure that a pond has a shore. A lake certainly does.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, thus my distancing language. Would I be right, though, in thinking that most Brits would not say "Let's go to the beach," but "to the seaside?" (And once arrived at the actual sandy bit and engaged in building sand castles, *is* it "the beach," or something else?)

Comment: I think we would say "let's go to the beach" if we were already at or near the coast. Once on the sandy part, we are definitely 'on the beach'. (But not always sand: it can be pebbles/shingle).

Comment: @WeatherVane Meanwhile, I'd stand by my assertion that a pond has a shore, though at some point, common sense takes over: a puddle doesn't have "a shore," so a pond that is little more than a glorified puddle might be putting on airs to claim one, but a respectable one ought to. I find specific idiomatic usages inexplicably suggesting themselves to my mind: it can be "the lake shore," but must be "the shore of the pond." (Likewise "the shore of the river," as vs "the riverbank". Meanwhile, we know that "she sells seashells by *the seashore*"...

Comment: That might be the difference of the conception of a pond. In UK a pond is quite small: say a duck pond a few metres across. In US I think Walden was called a pond, which we might call a lake. Not to mention the Atlantic Ocean ;) UV for the answer anyway.

Comment: Seconding the comments about strand/beach/seaside: "strand" is very unusual on the whole; "beach" is the sandy bit by the water, whereas the "seaside" is "the area near the sea" more generally.

Comment: @psmears I guess that's where the remaining regional difference lies: I might go "on vacation to the beach," meaning the coastal area, while you might go "on holiday to the seaside." Though we're getting off the OP's topic...

Comment: @WeatherVane True; a garden koi pond shouldn't be entitled to a "shore." I was thinking of a "horse pond" common on a farm, something more on the lines of 30m or so. One important point, Swenglish: wherever one draws the line, for any body of water too small to have a "shore," your suggestion of "edge" is best (e.g. "the edge of the puddle," "the edge of the koi pond").